# setFormula adds "=" in front of the value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

A13 cell wanted result : `https://forms.gle/1234`

A13 cell now result : `=https://forms.gle/1234`

because of `=` sheet send Error message `#ERROR!`

I want to delete `=`.

```
function quiz_form(){
var form = FormApp.create('New Form').setIsQuiz(true);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = form.getPublishedUrl()
spreadsheet.getRange('A13').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(ss)
spreadsheet.getRange('F17').activate();

var ss = form.getPublishedUrl()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

That is because [setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula) will add `=` by default in front of the value you are passing. You need to use [setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) instead.

Replace:

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula(ss)`

with:

`spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(ss)`

**Solution:**

```
function quiz_form(){
var form = FormApp.create('New Form').setIsQuiz(true);
Logger.log('Published URL: ' + form.getPublishedUrl());
Logger.log('Editor URL: ' + form.getEditUrl());
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ss = form.getPublishedUrl();
spreadsheet.getRange('A13').activate();
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue(ss);
spreadsheet.getRange('F17').activate();

var ss = form.getPublishedUrl();
}
```